# Why SharedPreferences is not initializing in this code?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I was just wondering why in Dart/Flutter my variable pref is not being initialized, I get the `Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'prefs' has not been initialized.` exception in the `getString()` function. Do someone know why?
Thanks for taking the time of reading my question.

```
class NewsApiRepository {


  NewsApiRepository() {
    initializeSharedPrefs();
  }

  late SharedPreferences prefs;


  void getSavedNews() {

    final codedData = prefs.getString(key); //Exception thrown here

  }

  void initializeSharedPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
  

}
```

Comment: The code that is initializing `prefs` is asynchronous, which means it will only run when it completes and then only the next time the asynchronous queue is checked. If the code that calls the constructor later synchronously calls `getSavedNews` before that happens, `prefs` wouldn't be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes time to initialize prefs. I suggest initializing once time only to avoid calling await SharedPreferences.getInstance() every time you call NewsApiRepository().

Here is one example to do that:

1. Define your class

```dart
class NewsApiRepository {

  SharedPreferences prefs;

  NewsApiRepository._(this.prefs);

  static NewsApiRepository? _instance;

  static NewsApiRepository getInstance() => _instance!;

  static void init(SharedPreferences pref) {
    _instance = NewsApiRepository._(pref);
  }

  void getSavedNews() {
    final codedData = prefs.getString(key);
  }

}
```

2. Call init inside main method

```dart
Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  NewsApiRepository.init(prefs);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: In Dart, it's cleaner to use the factory constructor to implement singletons than static functions.